# Unassigned local variable mystery

Tags: c#, clr

```
    int x;
    if (Q())
        x = 123;
    if (R())
        Console.WriteLine(x); // illegal

    int x;
    if (Q())
        x = 123;
    if (false)
        Console.WriteLine(x); // legal!!
```

May I know why second one is legal while former one is throwing 'using unassigned local variable' compile time exception?

Comment: since the second code is not reachable by the compiler, due to  if(false). Though the compiler shall throw warning on this.

Comment: You copied the code from a blog post but you forgot to copy the explanation: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2012/03/05/why-are-local-variables-definitely-assigned-in-unreachable-statements.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This tells compiler that the condition under if in the statement given below will never execute, so the constraint of unused variable does not apply to it.

```
if (false)
        Console.WriteLine(x); // legal!!
```

Answer (score 1):

Because the second one is eliminated by compiler as never executed.

Answer (score 1):

If Q() == FALSE and R() == true, x is not set and it will try to use it.

Comment: That only explains why the first one gives an error, not why the second one doesn't.